# Is it okay to trust your health to a mushroom hunters guide?

Tags: food, mushrooms

If I were to go mushroom hunting on a hike, Should I trust a field guide, or do a little research on it first? I've heard of too many deaths caused by mushroom eaters making a mistaken identification in a field guide.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most of the mushrooms you will find in a guide are low risk because they don't have similarities to poisonous ones - if you have a good guide it should point out the ones where identification is more difficult.

Avoid those ones and you will be much safer!